# Can a GFI receptacle die coincidentally at the same time as wall drilling?

Tags: hvac, gfci, electrical-panel

A little background:

I just moved into a rental house and a week later the property owner had a new wall-mounted AC/heating unit that required a bit of drilling through the wall installed. I opened the door for them, went to work, and came back about 5 hours later to make sure things were locked up. *The electricity in about half the (small) house was dead (for about a week), and the breaker switch would not stay on.* After talking to the electricians the HVAC company hired, we assumed that the guys had drilled through something.

Fast forward, electricity restored and the cooling system was working, but I had a really bad experience with them, so I left a bad review online. Later that day, I was met by the owner of the company at my house who bullied me into removing the review, claiming none of the bad things were their fault and that **the electrical problems were coincidental - in the 5 hours I was gone while they were working on installing the units, a GFCI receptacle had apparently died through no fault of their own, though they *generously* replaced it on their dime.**

Obviously this is possible, but I find it very unlikely. **How long do GFCI receptacles normally last, and what are the possible ways these guys could have caused or triggered the electrical problems I experienced?** I'm looking for explanations to help me understand what happened, or if I should take their word for it.

Comment: Yes, a GFCI breaker or receptacle can die at the same time as someone is drilling in the wall. Not likely, but it can happen. Hard to tell what your question is, or if it's just a rant. Please edit to clarify.

Comment: I felt the last paragraph made it obvious. What is the lifespan of a GFCI switch, and what kind of activity done by HVAC workers could cause power to die in part of my house?

Answer (score 3):

I agree that the question is a bit vague. I get the impression you're looking to either accept or absolve yourself of blame for the blowup with the HVAC company. My thoughts:

Sure, coincidences happen. You don't need us to tell you that. GFCI receptacles can last from zero to many days.

It's unlikely that the receptacle was damaged remotely without a heavy load on it, such as a refrigerator. Either a cable was shorted, and that resulted in damaging current through it to some load, or the receptacle itself was damaged. You'd know if the latter was the case, and without forensic analysis you can't know about the former. Of course, it's possible that there are factors you and I don't know about.

Finally, it's odd that you as a tenant got so involved. In the future, let your landowner handle it. Go get a pizza. :)

Comment: @ChrisM I would agree, but it became my fight when the electricity in half my house was out for a week.

Comment: @TBear I disagree.  That's something I would take up with said property owner.  They hired the contractor, so they should be the one dealing with any issues between the tenant and the contractor.

Comment: @ChrisM I think this is getting a bit off topic, but I also took it up with my landlord who deducted some rent for that month. However, as I was in the middle of living in a place where this work was done, I interacted with the contractors, so I feel justified in reviewing them online. And I'm a prospective home owner who is trying to learn its ins-and-outs , so I'm going to involve myself in this, hence me asking opinions here.

Comment: @TBear it is, I agree.  My point is simply that bringing up this issue with the landlord allows them to use their leverage as the paying customer.  The contractor isn't technically beholden to you as you are not in the contract.  I understand learning and interacting with the contractors as a tenant myself, however, your landlord is in a much better position to handle this than you are.  You are free to disagree, of course, and I will say no more here.

Comment: electricity out for a week --> that's **your landlord** letting you down.  He alone is responsible for the contractor's mistakes and you need to hold his feet to the fire directly.  Consider the converse: you buy your house with an in-law which you AirBnB, and  there's no A/C due to an error made by a contractor.  Whose responsibility is it?   Much success in business comes from being able to answer that question correctly.

Answer (score 2):

The GFCI blew, and was fixed by replacing it.  So we know in fact that it was the GFCI that failed.

The contractor also took responsibility for it, and replaced it on their dime, *which is a rather odd behavior if they had nothing to do with it*. Which confirms that they did indeed use it, certainly for tools, and probably gave it more of a workout than it's gotten in ages.

For whatever reason: maybe they overloaded it, maybe it's just old, maybe it was manufactured in the People's Republic of Cheese, their use was the last straw for the unit. In any case it's a $16 unit and just not worth fighting a customer over.

Or alternately, they *merely tripped it*, and it didn't reset because there was one or more GFCIs upstream that also tripped, and they either didn't know to look, or couldn't find them... and those were later found by the guy who replaced the GFCI.  Stuff like that happens all the time.

Comment: Plus one, but I disagree that it was odd behavior. As a former contractor I can see myself taking such measures to appease an angry or frustrated customer, regardless of fault.

Comment: @isherwood exactly, it's only a $16 bit. I meant if they had never used the receptacle.